# @keyframes animation behind text

Tags: css, css-animations

I have four animated `div` elements that are rotating inside a `section` element. The `div` elements need to go underneath the text (assuming it has a background) so that there are not clashing lines, so what I have tried to do is to add `background-color: #aeaeae; padding: 5px;` to the `section p` style, but the `div` elements still rotate on top of the text.

I have also tried adding `z-index` to both `div` and `section p` elements but it doesn't seem to be working. I have also tried wrapping the `p` element in a `span` tag and changing the display style.

```css
@keyframes lines {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(390deg);}
}

section {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0;
}

section p {
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    padding: 5px;
}

.section-1 {
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2px;
}
.line-1 {
    right: 521px;
    top: 33px; 
    animation: lines linear 100s infinite;
}
.line-2 {
    left: 9;
    top: 551px; 
    animation: lines linear 140s infinite;
}
.line-3 {
    left: -212px;
    top: 29px; 
    animation: lines reverse 120s infinite;
}
.line-4 {
    left: -400px;
    top: 20px; 
    animation: lines reverse 80s infinite;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
  <div class="line line-1"></div>
  <div class="line line-2"></div>
  <div class="line line-3"></div>
  <div class="line line-4"></div>
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare malesuada risus. Pellentesque vel neque a quam vehicula egestas. Cras vestibulum nisi lorem, nec dictum nisi luctus eget. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    Nunc maximus, velit at blandit pulvinar, est nisl sodales leo, eu scelerisque ante mauris sed purus.</p>
  <p>Maecenas blandit nec felis vel tincidunt. Curabitur id nibh dui. Ut suscipit interdum sem, sed auctor enim dignissim et. Nam luctus augue sit amet ullamcorper tincidunt. Donec posuere condimentum enim in dignissim. Ut purus ante, vehicula in luctus
    non, vestibulum non ipsum. Etiam semper urna sed nunc ornare.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Try setting `position:relative;` along with `z-index` if needed.

Comment: Can you help me understand why this solution worked?

Comment: You could also use `position: static;` with `z-index` if you want.

Comment: @KarsonKalt `z-index` only works "for a positioned box (that is, one with any position other than static)", see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) spec.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Pangloss for the answer:

"z-index only works "for a positioned box (that is, one with any position other than static)", see MDN spec"